# Laravel Sqlite column index out of range

Tags: laravel, sqlite, phpunit

When running tests using phpunit I'm getting a not so nice exception

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 column index out of range (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "attachments" where "id" = f3bad3ad-a888-41bc-b6fd-9a5998f6b527`

The Attachment.Id is a UUID and the column is defined as primary key. When running the tests I am using SQLite with an in-memory db.

When switching over to MySQL I do not get an error anymore. I don't really know why the query would cause an error.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure the property `public $incrementing = false;` is set on the model.

2) The migration should be `$table->uuid('id')->primary();`

3) Add the below function to the model:

```
public function getKeyType()
{
    return 'string';
}
```

4) To diagnose, create a `database.sqlite` and allow the test to run on that DB. Diagnose the size of the ID column. Does it fit the UUID string? If it actually doesn't, you may have to update your Laravel app or edit your migrations so if it's running on Sqlite, it will create a string column with the appropriate length.

Comment: Hi, I created the SQLite database and ran the query on it, works perfectly fine. So I'm clueless why it won't work when running phpunit.  See [sqlite db](https://imgur.com/a/DkyLGld)